# Meteor with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, meteor, aurelia

I want to use Meteor on my next project but also i want to use it with aurelia because aurelia is amazing. 
   There is a package for this https://github.com/TsumiNa/meteor-aurelia but last changes made at Jan 12, 2016 and aurelia resently relaese its 1.0 version.And i couldnt find any up to date package. 
   What should i do in this situation. should i trust that package or making meteor work with aurelia is simple think that i can do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differently from angular-meteor, aurelia does not have a similar project framework, and reling on outdated packages is risky.

We've tried TsumiNa/metor-aurelia and it had dependencies version problems.

So we developed an aurelia-meteor skeleton project that might be up to date with aurelia and meteor.

You can clone it on: https://github.com/Procempa/meteor-aurelia-seed/

Yet nowadays we are using pure aurelia client front-end with meteor as back-end only, by using ddp connections directly to access meteor methods and subscriptions (https://github.com/mondora/asteroid).

Comment: How come you switched to Asteroid from the skeleton you build and how does it work for you?